# admob with multiple framgents

Tags: android, admob

I have a question about admob. I have an activity with 3 fragments.I have a button on each fragment to go to the next fragment.

Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2 -> Fragment 3

Can i have different ads on each fragment? I mean I want to have a banner on  Fragment1 and Fragment2 and an interstitial ad on Fragment3. 
I know I can only have one ad per activity.
Does it mean that what I want to do is violate the admobs rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AdMob publisher guideline](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307237?hl=en) has the following about the number of ads per page:

> **Number of ads per page**
>
> The number of ads on a single screen should not exceed one if the ad is fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, only one ad should be visible on screen at a time.

As can be seen, there is no restriction as to the number of ads per `Activity`, only that at any point of time, a single screen should not have more than one ad.  So, if your fragments get replaced by each other, and at any point of time only one ad is present on the screen, you can have different ads in these fragments. You also have to consider the different layouts that you present (for example, if all the fragments are shown at a time in a single screen in the tablet layout, you need to take care that only one ad is visible).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very next explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a restriction of 3 ads per scrolling page in total.

> The number of ads on a single screen should not exceed one if the ad
>   is fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, only
>   one ad should be visible on the screen at a time, and, according to
>   the AdSense program policies, publishers may place no more than 3 ad
>   units on one entire page.